# Debo consultar un campo en un tabla y ver si existe un valor

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

En una tabla tengo el campo CM1_CUENTA donde un usuario puede tener muchas cuentas pero debo saber si entre todos ellas existe el numera 2365xxxx o 53152001 para realizar una accion y si no existe ninguno realizar otra accion

```
consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM TCMOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CM1_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "' AND CM1_TIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' AND CM1_NUM LIKE '%" + TBCausacion.Text + "'";
            if (lector.Read())
            {
                cuenta1 = lector["CM1_CUENTA"].ToString();
                //textBox4.Text = cuenta1;
                if (int.Parse(cuenta1) == 2365)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Existe 1");
                    TBRete.Text = lector["CM1_VALORH"].ToString();
                }
                else if (int.Parse(cuenta1) == 53152001)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Existe 2");
                    TBRetenAsum.Text = lector["CM1_VALORD"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    TBTotal1.Text = lector["CM1_VALORH"].ToString();
                }
            }
```

mi requerimiento seria como traer a una variable "cuenta1" si encuentra el 2365xxx o el 53152001 para realizar la accion y si no esta en ninguna cuenta simplemente guardar en un textbox un valor.
el valor 2365 viene normalmente "23659999" osea que los primeros 4 numeros son los que necesito en el caso de 2365

Comment: y con el codigo que tienes arriba que error te sale ?, no se si entendi mal, pero ya intentaste con `split() ` ?

Comment: No hay error lo que pasa es que me trae cualquier cuenta y necesito que busque entre todas las cuentas la que tenga 2365 si la tiene y no e intentado con split() por ejemplo hago la consulta y se que entre esas cuenta esta el 2365 pero me trae 45698 por ejemplo

Comment: entonces lo que debes es recorrer la consulta con una estructura ciclica hasta encontrar el valor deseado, me hago entender ?

Comment: Si entiendo mi problema es que soy novato en SQL y no sabria como hacer esa consulta

Comment: bueno, dejame te muestro como se recorren las consultas...

Comment: abajo te deje una respuesta... hasta donde te entensdi :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segun lo entendido, lo que necesitas es recorrer todas las consultas, asi que deacuerdo a lo leido deberia quedar asi:

```
consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM TCMOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CM1_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text 
    + "' AND CM1_TIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' AND CM1_NUM LIKE '%" + TBCausacion.Text + "'";
    //como dices que la consulta te trae varias filas de resultados, entonces, recorremos la consultas fila por fila
    // y en cada fila comparamos si se cumple cada condicion
    while (lector.Read())
    {
        cuenta1 = lector["CM1_CUENTA"].ToString();
        //textBox4.Text = cuenta1;
        if (cuenta1.StartsWith("2365"))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Existe 1");
            TBRete.Text = lector["CM1_VALORH"].ToString();
            break //este es opcional por si solo quieres que termine el ciclo cuando encuentres 2365
        }
        else if (cuenta1.StartsWith("53152001"))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Existe 2");
            TBRetenAsum.Text = lector["CM1_VALORD"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            TBTotal1.Text = lector["CM1_VALORH"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Espero este te sirva bro xD... ReNiceCode...

Comment: si te sirvio ? asi ?

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasarlo a string y preguntar si ese campo empieza con 2365, con `StartsWith`

```
 if (cuenta1.StartsWith("2365"))
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que la consulta me trae muchas cuentas diferentes entre ellas puede estar el numero 2365 lo que necesito es que si esta en alguna cuenta lo traiga "CM1_CUENTA" este es el campo y puede tener por ejemplo 123456 o 654789 o 236545689 y todas esas cuentas pertenecen al mismo usuario

Answer (score 0):

Como lo agarras como String solo tendrías que hacer esto a tu código

Lo que entiendo es que CM1_CUENTA contiene varios valores lo que puedes hacer es algo asi:

```
consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM TCMOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CM1_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "' AND CM1_TIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' AND CM1_NUM LIKE '%" + TBCausacion.Text + "'";
    if (lector.Read())
    {
        cuenta1 = lector["CM1_CUENTA"].ToString();
        //textBox4.Text = cuenta1;
        if (cuenta1.Contains("2365")) //Cambio
        {
            int emp = cuenta1.IndexOf("2365", 0) + 4;
            int ter = cuenta1.IndexOf(" ", emp);
            TBRete.Text = cuenta1.Substring(emp, ter - emp);
        }
        else if (cuenta1.Contains("53152001")) //Cambio
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Existe 2");
            int emp = cuenta1.IndexOf("53152001", 0) + 8;
            int ter = cuenta1.IndexOf(" ", emp);
            TBRetenAsum.Text = cuenta1.Substring(emp, ter - emp);
        }
        else
        {
            TBTotal1.Text = lector["CM1_VALORH"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias pero lo que pasa es que la consulta me trae muchas cuentas diferentes entre ellas puede estar el numero 2365 lo que necesito es que si esta en alguna cuenta lo traiga "CM1_CUENTA" este es el campo y puede tener por ejemplo 123456 o 654789 o 236545689 y todas esas cuentas pertenecen al mismo usuario solo si no existe 2365 ni 53152001 no haria nada

Comment: Entonces seria mas por SQL verdad??. seria algo así      consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM TCMOVIMIENTOCONTABLE WHERE CM1_TERCERO LIKE '%" + TBNit.Text + "' AND CM1_TIPO = '" + comboBoxTipo.Text + "' AND CM1_NUM LIKE '%" + TBCausacion.Text + "' AND (CM1_CUENTA LIKE '2365%' OR CM1_CUENTA LIKE '53152001%')";

Comment: eso si te llego a entender

Comment: Lo que pasa es que debe recorrer todas las cuentas de ese usuario y ver si en alguna de ellas existe 2365

Comment: mira mi editado si te ayuda